# Drag and drop events are not wokring inside Quill editor

Tags: drag, quill, drop

I was trying to move the content from one position to another inside quill editor . in quill 1.3.7 version drag and drop event listener like dragstart,dragover,dragenter,dragleave,drop,dragend was working but it is not working with quill js version 2.0.0-beta.2

I have tried different quill js versions like beta.0 and dev.4 but still not working